# JavaScript Error In JQRangeSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

Seem to be having some issues with the JQRangeSlider. Trying to implement this tool into an MVC project.  After the slider is called the alert is never reached.  Is there a bug?  I have this working in another project in Dreamweaver, though it renders fine in the live preview mode it does not work bringing it to any browser.  Here's my code...

```
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    Layout = "";
    }

<html>
<head>
<title>"Slider"</title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/start/jquery-           ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/slider/CSS/classic.css")" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css" />



    <script src="@Url.Content("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/slider/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/slider/Scripts/jQRangeSliderMouseTouch.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/slider/Scripts/jQRangeSliderDraggable.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/slider/Scripts/jQRangeSliderBar.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/slider/Scripts/jQDateRangeSliderHandle.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/slider/Scripts/jQRangeSliderLabel.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/slider/Scripts/jQEditRangeSliderLabel.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/slider/Scripts/jQRangeSlider.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/slider/Scripts/jQEditRangeSlider.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


<body>

<div class="page-header">
    <h2>Test</h2>

</div>
<div id="slider" style="width:200px;"></div>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#slider").editRangeSlider();
        alert("whocareswhateverbye");

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you don't mean `<title="slider"></title>` but rather `<title=>slider</title>` or something

Comment: What error does you browser error console show?

Comment: @Michael I was working with Shane on this. You are correct about the title but it is not the issue. The browser is not showing any error. Firebug was used. No slider was shown. If editRangeSlider is changed to slider it works as a basic slider.
Code after the initialization of the editRangeSlider is not reached making one think it is a js error. (did not mean to post this as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is failing at

```
 $("#slider").editRangeSlider();
```

due to a compatibility issue with jQuery 1.7, so it's never reaching the alert.

It's working fine with jQuery 1.8 as demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QwAqy/1/